# How to have an address inside a solidity Struct?

Tags: solidity, addresses, struct

## My problem

Suppose I have this struct:

```
struct TextThatWorks {
        bytes32 text;
        uint reads;
}
```

How can I add a `address` variable to it?

## What I tried

I tried simply adding `address someadress;` inside the struct declaration, like so:

```
struct TextThatDoesNotWork {
        bytes32 text;
        uint reads;
        address addr;
}
```

I have seen many examples doing this exact same thing. Example: [Solidity Docs](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.21/structure-of-a-contract.html#struct-types)

But when I do this, my functions break.

## What happens when I try the above

#### What works

So, in my contract I have a Text array:

`TextThatWorks[] public textArray;`

And I have a function to recall the texts inside this array, which returns arrays:

```
function listTexts () public view returns (bytes32[], uint[]) {

        bytes32[] memory texts = new bytes32[](textArray.length);
        uint[] memory readsArray = new uint[](textArray.length);

        for (uint i = 0; i < textArray.length; i++){
            texts[i] = textArray[i].text;
            readsArray[i] = textArray[i].reads;
        }

        return (texts, readsArray);

}
```

This returns a nice array in the format `[["some hexadecimal example"],[12]]`

#### What does not work

The second struct, `TextThatDoesNotWork`, only differs of `TextThatWorks` because it has an `address` field.

When I use it, my `listTexts()` function stops working. It always returns empty arrays like `[[],[],[]]`

To accomodate the additional field, my `listTexts()` function becomes the following:

```
function listTexts () public view returns (bytes32[], uint[], address[]) {

        bytes32[] memory texts = new bytes32[](textArray.length);
        uint[] memory readsArray = new uint[](textArray.length);
        address[] memory addresses = new address[](textArray.length);

        for (uint i = 0; i < textArray.length; i++){
            texts[i] = textArray[i].text;
            readsArray[i] = textArray[i].reads;
            addresses[i] = textArray[i].addr;
        }

        return (texts, readsArray, addresses);

}
```

## How I fill the array

```
function put(bytes32 _text, uint _reads) public returns (uint){
    return textArray.push(TextThatDoesNotWork({
        text: _text,
        reads: _reads,
        addr: msg.sender
    }))-1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you fill the array properly

```
TextThatDoesNotWork[] textArray;

function put(bytes32 s, uint r, address a) public {
    textArray.push(TextThatDoesNotWork({
        text: s, 
        reads: r,
        addr: a
    }));
}
```

[image]

Comment: Check out my edit. I added your code. I tried it, but I still cannot make it work.

There's something catchy though. Whenever I run `contract.put("text", 200)`, I  get a transaction hash in the console, instead of the index returned by the function. Could the problem be the way I call the function `put()`?

Comment: Let's solve issues one by one, because return value from `put` function is another issue. What do you have after actions: deployment contract -> call `put(0x1221, 10)` -> call `listTexts()`?

Comment: btw, `contract.put("text", 200)` will not work, because first parameter has type `bytes32`, you need to convert string to bytes32, you can use `web3.utils.fromAscii("text")` function

Comment: it does work, as described in the question text. My guess is that the contract makes this conversion for me. The problem arises when I add the `address` attribute to the struct. It simply stops working, but before appending that attribute, it works!

Comment: I'm using the geth console to test this contract. Without the `address` attribute in the struct, I can deploy the contract, call `contract.put("some text", 200)`, and see the new data using `contract.listTexts()`.

Comment: I thought we are in discussion of full version only(with address). Here is full version of code https://gist.github.com/aquiladev/75ac4f981075caa059ccfdd71125899b Make sure that you run it with right version of solidity. If it will not work, most probably problem in communication with contract.

Comment: so, it seems you and I are both right. I wasn't using the Remix IDE to test my contract, I was compiling on my own in bash terminal, and using geth console. So, you were right because on Remix, I can't just pass a string. I really have to pass text in hex format. But when I interact with my contract via geth console, this is unnecessary. To talk about my problem, I still cannot use an address field in the struct when testing via geth console. It does work via Remix  IDE though. I guess I must be doing something wrong when compiling? Or could this be a bug in the compiler?

Comment: It would be good to check version of compiler, but I'm not sure that is a case, only if you have really old version. I would try to compile via `solc` or `truffle` with tests.

Comment: I see he's trying to return a value from the put() function but I thought you can't return values from state-changing functions, only view functions.